# I need to add an array of images that can be changed with button images or number entry using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, image

I have a series of images that are being assigned to the numbers 1-200. I want to have a single page that begins by loading image 1, and if the right arrow button is pressed, it goes to page 2, and then if the left arrow button is pressed, it goes back to page 1, and so on. Alternatively, the user may type a number that is 1-200 into a text box, and it will take the user to that page. I could do the first part in HTML, but it would require lots of page reloads, which is a hassle and is bad for the site, and I wouldn't be able to get the box to work. I have had no previous experience with JS, and so I don't know where to start. I haven't been able to find anything on Google, either.
What should I look into to make this happen? Also, could you provide a snippet of code that could make this work? Obviously I'd have to type the entire array in myself, but some quick help would be much appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="main">
<img src="photo1.jpg" alt="" id="mainImg">

</div> 

<div id="imglist">
<a href="javascript:previousImage('mainImg')"><img src="previous.jpg" alt=""></a>
<a href="javascript:nextImage('mainImg')"><img src="next.jpg" alt=""></a>
<script>
var imgArray = new Array();

imgArray[0] = new Image();
imgArray[0].src = 'photo1.jpg';

imgArray[1] = new Image();
imgArray[1].src = 'photo2.jpg';

imgArray[2] = new Image();
imgArray[2].src = 'photo3.jpg';


function nextImage(element)
{
    var img = document.getElementById(element);

    for(var i = 0; i < imgArray.length;i++)
    {
        if(imgArray[i].src == img.src) // << check this
        {
            if(i === imgArray.length){
                document.getElementById(element).src = imgArray[0].src;
                break;
            }
            document.getElementById(element).src = imgArray[i+1].src;
            break;
        }
    }
}

function previousImage(element)
{
   var img = document.getElementById(element);

   for(var i = 0; i < imgArray.length;i++)
   {
      if(imgArray[i].src == img.src)
      {
         if(i === 0){
            document.getElementById(element).src = imgArray[imgArray.length-1].src;
            break;
         }
         else{
            document.getElementById(element).src = imgArray[i-1].src;
            break;
         }
      }
   }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Current, working code for the arrows. Thanks to anpsmn for getting me there.

Comment: Can you show us some html?

Comment: @DavidTansey I updated it with my current code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a js error, the inner If condition is not closed properly for previous function. Try to debug always for such errors.

```
function previousImage(element)
{
   var img = document.getElementById(element);

   for(var i = 0; i < imgArray.length;i++)
   {
      if(imgArray[i].src == img.src)
      {
         if(i === 0){
            document.getElementById(element).src = imgArray[imgArray.length-1].src;
            break;
         }// this was not there before
         else{
            document.getElementById(element).src = imgArray[i-1].src;
            break;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: That fixes the error of it not going forward an image, but now how do I make it go backwards an image? The [i-1] doesn't work, and I changed the i++ to a ++i, but that still doesn't do it.

Comment: In the above code, I am checking if it's 0 then the prev image would be the last image that is 3rd in this case(circular).

Comment: Absolutely brilliant, if I could upvote, I would. I'll bookmark the page and do it once I reach 15 rep.
Thanks a ton!
Now what would I do to get the text box working? Does JS have a getline or cin type of function that I could compare to an if statement?
Set a var for user input, then have the input go through a set of ifs/else ifs, right?

Comment: You can accept the answer by clicking on the check :). Yes, you can use `document.getElementById("textboxid").value` and compare.